Dynamically fetching the vaults secrets from 1Pass
How can I dynamically fetch the secrets from 1Password into Github action env variable?
Tried the following to dynamically fetch the item name which is not replacing the $col2 value
if the input param is "prod", then the col2 should be replaced accordingly to fetch the password from prod. How to dynamically replace the item/section ?

 - name: Load secret
        uses: 1password/load-secrets-action@v2
        with:
          # Export loaded secrets as environment variables
          export-env: true
        env:
          OP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.OP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN }}
          DATABASE_PWD: "op://personal/$col2/password"
          DATABASE_USER: "op://personal/$col2/username" 


Provided that col2 is a workflow input, you can inject it into the values that define location of your secrets like this:
- name: Load secret
  uses: 1password/load-secrets-action@v2
  with:
    export-env: true
  env:
    OP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.OP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_TOKEN }}
    DATABASE_PWD: "op://personal/${{ inputs.col2 }}/password"
    DATABASE_USER: "op://personal/${{ inputs.col2 }}/username" 


how to loop through the locations, if the col2 has to be fetched from a file? can that be done  in github actions?

You can read the value from a file and set it into an environment variable in bash echo col2=$value >> $GITHUB_ENV. Then env var col2 is accessible to all steps in a job as ${{ env.col2 }}
